# 外枠のある背景を作成したい．

Tags: android, xml, fragment

fragment.xmlの一番外枠のLinearLayoutで縦と幅をmatchparentに設定しているのですが端末の画面全体まで広がってくれずに中身のコンテンツの分までしか広がってくれません。
activity_main.xmlのLinearLayoutもmatchparentに設定しています。
画面いっぱいまで広げる方法をご教授お願いします。

Comment: 文章だけでは問題点がわかりませんので、レイアウトxmlのコードを貼り付けてください。

Answer (score 0):

> 画面いっぱいまで広げる方法

AppCompatActivityをActivityに変更してタイトルバーを無くす

テーマの変更をする

@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar

@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

https://akira-watson.com/android/theme-notitlebar.html

Answer (score 0):

タイトルと、質問文章がマッチしていない気もするのですが。
「アプリ表示領域が端末の画面全体まで広がってくれない」として回答いたします。

まずデフォルトのa.j.wさんの回答のようにXMLでタイトルバーのないテーマを指定するか、
あるいはjavaコード上でActivityクラスのrequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)をコールします。

次に、ステータスバーとナビバーを消去します。

```
View decor = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
decor.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION    //Navigation領域を消去
                           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN         //Statusbar領域を消去
                           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY); //immersiveモードを設定
```

恒久的にNaviBar,StatusBarを削除することは出来ず、画面下部Swipeで復帰してしまいます(Androidの仕様)

ご質問内容が「アプリ表示領域が端末の画面全体まで広がってくれない」でないのであれば、
現在発生している問題画面のスクリーンショットと期待動作のイメージ、
およびlayout.xml等をご提示いただければ正確な回答ができるかと思います。